# Fix denial of access (PHP)

Tags: php, html, session, authentication, restrict

I created a program where a user has to log in first. However, when I go to a certain page, the user can still view it even if s/he is not logged in. I actually have solved that (my program denies access when not logged in), but as it turned out, the program restricts the user type 'user' (btw, I have three user types: user, manager, admin) from logging in and only allows the manager and admin. 
Here's my code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";


function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 

  $isValid = False; 


  if (!empty($UserName)) { 

    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 

    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "invalid.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($QUERY_STRING) && strlen($QUERY_STRING) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $QUERY_STRING;
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Home </title>

</head>
<div align="center">
<img src="590px-HGST_CompanyLogo.svg.png" alt="Home" style="width:300;height:100">
<br><br><h3><font face="arial black"size="5"color="#002E8A"> Welcome, LAB USER! </font></h3></div>

<body>

<hr width="80%">
<center>

<a href="search.php" target="_blank"> <img src="search-button-png-hi.png" alt="Search error" style="width:200px;height:80px;border:0"></a> &nbsp;
<a href="form.php" target="_blank"><img src="report-button-png-hi.png" alt="Rerport error" style="width:200px;height:80px;border:0"></a> <br>
<a href="download.php" target="_blank"> <img src="download-button-2468711.jpg" alt="Download error files" style="width:200px;height:65px;border:0"><font size="5"></font></a>
&nbsp;
<a href="files/uploadfile.php" target="_blank"><image src="upload-button-png-hi.png" alt="Upload error reports" style="width:200px;height:65px;border:0"></a>
<br><br>

<table>
<ul>
<tr><td><font size="5"><li>Click <a href="files/uploadfile" target="_blank">here</a> to view uploaded files.
</tr></td></font>
</li>

</table>
<br><font size="5">
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a></font>
</center>
</font>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't have the problem you mention in the title, please edit the title to say what the problem actually is. Also don't add tags to the title.

Comment: remove this condition `if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}` just use ` session_start();` at top

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: `if (($strUsers == "") && true) { ` .... you might want to focus on that as well.